# NSXMLParser strange behavior with \n

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser, file-format

I'm developing an iOS 4 application that parses a XML file. A piece of XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<cards>
  <card id ="0">
    <name lang="es">The Mad</name>
    <description lang="es">...</description>
  </card>
...
</cards>
```

I use the following method to parse `<name lang="es">The Mad</name>`.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSXMLParserDelegate methods

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"DidStartElement: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"card"])
    {
        currentCard = [[Card alloc] init];
        NSString* arcaneNumber = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"];
        currentCard.Number = arcaneNumber;

        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
    {
        if ([[attributeDict objectForKey:@"lang"] isEqualToString:userLanguage])
        {
            currentProperty = kNameProperty;
            return;
        }
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"])
    {
        if ([[attributeDict objectForKey:@"lang"] isEqualToString:userLanguage])
        {
            currentProperty = kDescriptionProperty;
            return;
        }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!currentStringValue)
    {
        // currentStringValue is an NSMutableString instance variable
        currentStringValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:50];
    }
    [currentStringValue appendString:string];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
  didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"DidEndElement: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"card"])
    {
        [cards setObject:currentCard forKey:currentCard.Number];
        [currentCard release];
        currentCard = nil;

        return;
    }

    if (currentProperty == kNameProperty)
    {
        currentProperty = kNoneProperty;
        currentCard.Name = [currentStringValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        [currentStringValue release];
        currentStringValue = nil;

        return;
    }

    if (currentProperty == kDescriptionProperty)
    {
        currentProperty = kNoneProperty;
        currentCard.Description = currentStringValue;
        [currentStringValue release];
        currentStringValue = nil;

        return;
    }
}
```

After, parsing , I get on currentStringValue the following:

```
\n\nThe Mad
```

How can avoid these two '\n'? Why am I getting these two '\n'?

This xml file came from a Windows system, and I've used TextWrangler to covert it to Classic Mac format.

Comment: Can you show your implementation of didStartElement and didEndElement?

Comment: How are you creating the XML string that you feed into this parser? Is it possible that you are doing something that converts newline characters from your input XML into actual '\' 'n' characters BEFORE you parse?

Comment: All my code is here. I followed this guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `foundCharacters` delegate method also gets called for whitespace in between elements.  It will get called if there is say a newline between `<cards>` and `<card id=...`.

I suggest clearing `currentStringValue` at the top of `didStartElement` to discard any characters found before the start of the current element and to make sure only the characters inside the current element (not between) are captured by `foundCharacters`.

At the top of `didStartElement`, add:

```
[currentStringValue release];
currentStringValue = nil;
```

It is possible for an element's value to contain whitespace (so removing them in `didEndElement` could result in saving values that don't match the xml content).

Comment: If using currentStringValue as NSMutableArray. How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

On your end element method you can try stripping these out yourself from the current text string. Simply try searching for them on the string and replace them with @"". I like replacing these and unwanted blank entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it work for me ,

```
NSString *data= [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Use above line of code in **foundCharacters** method .

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;
 {
   NSString *data= [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

  if(dString == nil){
   dString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:data];
 }else
  {
   [dString appendString:data];
  }
 }
```

Hope this will help for some one .